# ¿De dónde proviene el vocablo "el mío"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, venezuela

"El mío" es muy usada en Venezuela, específicamente en su capital Caracas.
Un ejemplo de la misma pudiese ser:

> Ven acá el mío...

¿A qué se le atribuye dicha palabra a la hora de mencionarla en alguna frase?

Comment: Quieres decir que para decirle a alguien "ven aquí" le dices "Ven acá el mio..." o que para pedir que alguien te traiga algo le dices ""Ven acá el mio X"? Puedes ampliar ese ejemplo de uso añadiendo algo del contexto?

Comment: Si, coloquialmente hablando, hago énfasis en los adolescentes, tienden a hacer uso de esa frase, para llamarse o pedir favor o algo parecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El Diccionario de americanismos recoge una entrada que parece coincidir con lo que mencionas:

> [**mío, -a**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=m%C3%ADo).
> I.  1.  m. y f. Cu. Persona afín o estimada. pop.

Eso sí, indica que se usa en Cuba, pero no en Venezuela. Siendo zonas caribeñas con rasgos lingüísticos parecidos, no creo descabellado afirmar que la palabra puede haber pasado a usarse también en el país sudamericano.

De hecho, la web Así hablamos la recoge:

> [**El mío**](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/El%20mio.php)
>
> Prostituta de los reos venezolanos normalmente hombres o forma de expresarse y referirse a un amigo.
>
> Amigo, persona allegada.
> *Qué pasó el mío*

<sub>Desconozco qué validaciones hace la web así hablamos, pues la frase de ejemplo aparece como *que paso el mio* [sic], con tres de las cuatro palabras sin la tilde que merecen.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

La expresión "el mio" es muy popular en las calles venezolanas y es un slang callejero que se utiliza para expresar cierta relación de amistad y compañerismo entre los jóvenes de las clases bajas.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio